# Any way to mute the sound yet keep it running in the background instead of stopping it completely?

Tags: c#, audio, mute

What the title says really, Right now I only know how to control the sound by using .Play and .Stop, however is there a way to mute the sound but still have it playing in the background?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
    private void muteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (muteButton.Text == "Mute")
        {

            muteButton.Text = "Unmute";
            _soundPlayer.Stop();
        }

        else
        {
            muteButton.Text = "Mute";
            _soundPlayer.PlayLooping();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Which sound? What are you talking about?

Comment: Just any imported sound, for instance a song that is running in the background, is there syntax to mute it but not stop it completely

Comment: "Running in the background". Chances are, how you mute it is determined by how it is running in the background. How are you playing this sound in the first place?

Comment: You should really include all of the required information in your question. For example, I only know now that `_soundPlayer` is a `System.Media.SoundPlayer` object, because I Googled `MSDN PlayLooping`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.playlooping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Rather than stopping playback, can you set the volume to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
private boolean playing = true;
private void muteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_soundPlayer.IsLoadCompleted)
    {
        if (playing)
           {
            _soundPlayer.Stop();
            playing = false;
            }
        else
            {
            _soundPlayer.Play();
             playing = true;
            }
    }
}
```